# Checkbox OnClick Event Not Working after partial Pageload (UpdatePanel)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in ASP.Net inside an UpdatePanel, in the gridview I have a Checkbox and a Button in every row. If the checkbox is checked, the button will be enabled. And if the checkbox is unchecked, the button will be disabled. On the first page load the jquery worked properly with no error in inspect element. But after I clicked the button, which run a data binding event, the gridview changed as desired, but an error appeared in inspect, and the click event didn't work.

Here are my aspx code

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/PopUp.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="abc.aspx.cs" Inherits="HMB.Sbadmin.Web.Pages.T.abc" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            chbActionEvent();
        });
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
                chbActionEvent();
            }
        }

        function chbActionEvent() {
                $('.master_grid span.UnSettled').each(function () {
                    var chbAction = $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('id');
                    $('#' + chbAction).change(function () {
                        var btnSettle = $(this).closest('tr').find(':submit').attr('id');
                        alert(chbAction + btnSettle);
                        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                            $('#' + btnSettle).attr('disabled', false);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#' + btnSettle).attr('disabled', true);
                        }
                    });
                });
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="gridContainer">
                <ul class="link_path">
                    <li>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_Clicked" CssClass="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" CausesValidation="false"  />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="dvMain" runat="server">
                    <asp:gridview ID="gvMain" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        CssClass="master_grid"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
                        OnRowDataBound="gvMain_RowDataBound"
                        OnRowCommand="gvMain_RowCommand">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chbAction" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="UnSettled"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltrSettle" Text='<%# Eval("Settle") %>' runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSettle" runat="server" CssClass="UnSettled uiButton uiButtonConfirm" CommandName="cmdSettle" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' CausesValidation="false" Enabled="false"/><br />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:gridview>

                    <div>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label> 
                    </div>        
                </div>        
            </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the error in inspect element :
[image]

I also have tried to put the code in RowDataBound:
`

```
protected void gvMain_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Row.RowType)
            {
                case DataControlRowType.Header:
                    setDataBoundHeader(e.Row);
                    break;
                case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                    if (gvMain.Rows.Count >= 0 && (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal || e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate))
                    {
                        setDataBoundList(e.Row);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
protected void setDataBoundList(GridViewRow row)
        {
            CheckBox chbAction = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chbAction");
            chbAction.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "chbActionEvent()");
        }
```

`

But, no luck.

Please help.

**Update 1.1 :**

Also tried this :`

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            chbActionEvent();
        });
        //function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        //    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
        //        chbActionEvent();
        //    }
        //}

        function chbActionEvent() {
                $('.master_grid span.UnSettled').each(function () {
                    var chbAction = $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('id');
                    $('#' + chbAction).change(function () {
                        var btnSettle = $(this).closest('tr').find(':submit').attr('id');
                        alert(btnSettle);
                        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                            $('#' + btnSettle).attr('disabled', false);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#' + btnSettle).attr('disabled', true);
                        }
                    });
                });
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(chbActionEvent);
    </script>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="gridContainer">
                <ul class="link_path">
```

`
But got the same error as the first code [image]

**Update 1.2** :

Tried debugging with Microsoft Visual Studio. On the first try, the button event works properly. But after the partial postback (after I clicked the button for the first time), the checkbox is still working properly (with error in inspect), but the button didn't do anything when clicked.

**Update 1.3** :

The btnSettle value :[image]

Comment: console your btnSettle variable..

Comment: the btnSettle variable always returns the correct id, for example : MainContent_gvMain_btnSettle_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution myself
the problem is in the sba.all.js, altered the code a bit and it all works

Answer (score 0):

You have to `bind` your `event` after partial call back. It's better to use `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(InIEvent);`.

Please add below code in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(chbActionEvent);
</script>
```

For more details about this, please check [Working with jQuery within the ASP.NET UpdatePanel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601683/Working-with-jQuery-within-the-ASP-NET-UpdatePanel).

Comment: i have added the code before the update panel and deleted the document.ready and the pageload.. but it's not working. do i supposed to keep the document.ready or not ?

Comment: on the first time the page loads, it's working, but after it does the partial load, the table loads correctly and it show different error than my code

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: a[b] is not a function

Comment: You can check my article that I've mention in answer. It will help you.

Comment: still not working, and got the same error as my first code :(

Comment: Your error comes from `$('#' + btnSettle).attr('disabled', false);`. Please check `var btnSettle = $(this).closest('tr').find(':submit').attr('id');`. What is the value of `btnSettle`.

Comment: please see the picture in my Update 1.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143860/discussion-between-csharpbd-and-prima-shella).